# Relative clauses: How do that-clauses differ from what-clauses?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Sometimes I can't see which clause fits the best. What "check-up" could be done to make sure which one is the right one?

For example,

**1) He will do anything that is needed. or He will do anything what is needed.**

**2) They always ignore that is so obvious. or They always ignore what is so obvious.**

**3) All that I have is yours. or All what I have is yours.**

My take is the correct ones are 1) that 2) that 3) what/that???

But I am not sure. I think it has to do something with different types or dependent clauses, but I don't know how to go about them in this case. Any suggestions?

Here is an interesting example

How do I know what I think, until I see what I say? VERSUS How do I know that I think, until I see what I say?

I think both are correct meaning two different things.

Comment: The correct word in all 3 examples is "*that*", unless you want to sound like the chimney sweep from Mary Poppins. In re: your final example, it is certainly possible to say either "What I think" or "That I think", but only "What I think" fts into the specific sentence you gave.

Comment: @DanBron Really? ***They always ignore that is so obvious.*** seems very wonky to me!!

Answer (score 4):

***That* and *Which***

Relative clauses with *which* or *that* usually modify nouns. The end result is  that the original noun becomes one big Noun Phrase and functions just like a large noun.

- Do you remember the **volcano** ***[which erupted whilst we were on holiday]***?

Here we see the noun *volcano* being modified by *which ... holiday*. The whole Noun Phrase *the volcano which erupted whilst we were on holiday* has the function of Direct Object  of the verb *remember*.

Notice that it is the word *which* that is the subject of *which erupted whilst we were on holiday* - not the word *volcano*. Rather, the word *volcano* is the ***antecedent*** for the pronoun *which*. This means that we interpret *which* within the clause through the word *volcano* which comes before it. In normal relative clauses, the pronoun *which* always has an antecedent. The relative word *that*, also appears in clauses in front of which there is some kind of noun as an antecedent:

- Do you remember the **volcano *[that erupted whilst we were on holiday]***?

So in both of these types of relatives clause we have an antecedent noun, which helps us interpret another element in the embedded relative clause.

***What***

If we compare the following sentences we''ll see that there's a very specific difference in relative clauses with *what*:

- **The things that** she did were thoughtful and useful.
- **The things which** she did were thoughtful and useful.
- **What** she did was thoughtful and useful.

or

- I liked **the thing(s) which** she did.
- I liked **the thing(s) that** she did.
- I liked **what** she did.

The big difference is that, as you can see, there's no antecedent noun for the relative clauses with *what*. The relative clauses with *which/that* all have *the things* as an antecedent. *What* takes the place of both the antecedent as well as the relative word.

**The Examples**

With regard to the Original Poster's examples:

> - 1) He will do **anything**  ***_***  is needed.

Here we see that there is an antecedent noun phrase, *anything*. Therefore we need to use *that* or *which*:

- *He'll do anything that's needed*.

[However, if we removed the noun phrase *anything* completely, then we could use *what*:

- He'll do what's needed.]

> - 2) They always ignore  ***_***   is so obvious.

Here there is no antecedent noun so we have to use *what*:

- They always ignore what's so obvious.

> - 3) **All** ***_***  I have is yours.

Here we find an antecedent noun, the pronoun *all*. We cannot therefore use *what*, but must use *that* instead. We could use *which* but when the antecedent is a pronoun like this it is often better to use *that*.

- All that I have is yours.

Regarding the Original Poster's last unnumbered example, consider the following:

> I know what I think.
>
> I know that I think.

The first sentence has a relative clause, *what I think* as a direct object. Within the relative clause itself, the object of *think* is understood as the item *what*.

The second sentence however does not have a relative clause. We know this is the case because there is no antecedent for *that*. The clause following *know* is a declarative content clause. The sentence has the same structure as *I know that Yetis exist* or *I know that you like cheese.*

In the second example,the clause *that I think* is the complement of the verb *know*. The verb *think* here has no object. The word *that* is a marker showing that the following clause is subordinate. In fact we can remove *that* entirely from the sentence and it will still be grammatical and still have the same meaning:

- I know I think. Or at least I believe I do.

**Conclusion**

To sum up, if there is an antecedent noun in the main clause then *that* or *which* appears at the front of the relative clause. We find *what* when there is no antecedent.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: +1, Fused-relatives and subordinate interrogative clauses alway cause me headaches because they can often look so similar (and often are ambiguous), and then toss in those subordinate clauses with "how", which pulls in the possibility of subordinate exclamative clauses, and that, well, is a big mess of possible confusion.

Comment: @F.E. Yes quite! I originally had an example along the lines of *I remember the trick that he did* --> *I remember what he did*, but that seemed really interrogative clause-ish to me so I changed it. I'm happier to put *declarative* on the *know what I think* though, and have, though I agree that it's a bit either way-ish ... (less happy with the *that which*, just because I'm not sure the definite aspect of *that* carries through ...)

Answer (score 1):

*That* always needs to refer to another word or clause in the context, *what* doesn't have to do that.

*What* is also used to form questions: what do you think? You don't ask "that do you think?"

A simple "trick" I use myself is that you can usually replace "what" by "that which" without changing the meaning:

1) He will do anything that is needed. or He will do anything what is needed.

*That* refers to *anything*. "He will do anything that which is needed" makes no sense. So, *that* is correct.

Note that without *anything*, *what* would be correct:
He will do what is needed; he will do *that which* is needed.

2) They always ignore that is so obvious. or They always ignore what is so obvious.

*That* does not refer to anything in the sentence. They ignore *that which* is obvious, so *what* is correct.

3) All that I have is yours. or All what I have is yours.

*That* refers to *all*. *All that which* makes no sense, so *that* is correct. Again, without *all*, it would be *What I have is yours*.

You last sentence is interesting:

> How do I know that I think?

That refers to *I think*, the action of thinking. So you wonder how you can know that you actually perform the act of thinking. One could say that question is answered by the fact you ask the question!

> How do I know what I think?

*What* can be replaced by "that which", you don't wonder *if* you think, but (about) *what* you think. Normally this version is the one you mean.

Note: as Janus Bahs Jacquet mentions, to make things a little less clear, in some dialects, *what* can be used instead of *that* in sentences like your first one. In that case, the important thing is , be consistent.

Comment: Did you mean to write _that which_? _That what_ is not used at all, to my knowledge. (Also, _what_ is actually used instead of _that_ in some dialects, mostly in Britain: “He’ll do anything what’s needed” is perfectly grammatical and commonplace in those dialects.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I need some more coffee before I translate language tricks from Dutch to English. Of course I meant _that which_.

Comment: I'm never quite sure that you blokes across the pond can think at all, let alone trying to understand what you think. I occasionally watch your "prime minister's questions" because that's one of the best comedy shows on TV. (Questions along the lines of "When, exactly, did the Prime Minister stop eating children for lunch?", and the responses to them are quite hilarious.)

Comment: @Araucaria yes, it should. Every so often my Dutch roots betray me :(